# Delayed key presses in pop OS 22.04 LTS (the slow keys feature is disabled)

Tags: keyboard

Occasionally, the responses that are supposed to be triggered by keyboard immediately are delayed by a rather long period of time (3 min or so I guess, excuse me I didn't time it when it occurred). Such has happened multiple times, though not always -- the response time would go back to normal after minutes, without logging out or restarting or any other apparent intervention. I had even reinstalled the system, which was to no avail.

By the way I have checked the "slow keys" feature in the settings, and it was off every time it happened. Turning it on or off does nothing during such incidents.

I am wondering what could have gone wrong as these incidents occur, and how to fix it to prevent them from ever happening again?